# 404 not found instead of login page in keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have create a realm and client , but when I am trying to login to get authorization code it is giving 404 page not found

### [image]

### [image]

### [image: Error]

```
http://localhost:8087/auth/realms/sample/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=sampleclient&response_type=code&state=fj8o3n7bdy1op5
```

This is the url which I am trying with access with the required query parameters mentioned in Keycloak docs

Am I doing something wrong or it's just that it can't work without any application